# Very simple, unexpected Low Performance of set(=)

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, variable-definitions

```
In[1]  AA = RandomInteger[10, 1000000]; BB = AA;

In[2]  Do[BB = AA;, 10000] // Timing

Out[2]  {0., Null}

In[3]  Do[BB[[77]] = i;, {i, 1, 10000}] // Timing

Out[3]  {0., Null}

In[4]  Do[BB[[i]] = i;, {i, 1, 10000}] // Timing

Out[4]  {0., Null}
```

From Out[2], we see **setting a variable to a large list** takes no time.

From Out[3],Out[4], we see **setting an element of a list to a number** takes no time.

But

```
In[5]  Do[BB = AA; BB[[77]] = i;, {i, 1, 10000}] // Timing

Out[5]  {3.04688, Null}
```

alternately **setting a variable to a large list** + **setting an element of a list to a number** takes long time.

Q1) How can we explain it ?

Q2) In fact, mathematica reported it took 3.04688 seconds, but in fact it took about 20 seconds (physical watch) to get Out[5]. Personaly there have been some differences in the past, but this is the first time I've seen such a big difference.

Comment: Line [5] is the only one where a deep copy of the full AA→BB is done in every loop iteration. Line [2] can be done with a shallow (lazy) copy because BB is not being edited and so no actual data copying is required (only some reference counts need to be updated); but in line [5] the shallow copy `BB=AA` is followed by a write access `BB[[77]]=i`, which triggers [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and which takes substantial amounts of time.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know there is a concept like shallow (lazy) copy.

Comment: @Roman I found your comment very insightful. Would you consider turning it into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that, like all modern software, Mathematica implements [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). From the Wikipedia:

> Copy-on-write (COW), sometimes referred to as implicit sharing or shadowing, is a resource-management technique used in computer programming to efficiently implement a "duplicate" or "copy" operation on modifiable resources. If a resource is duplicated but not modified, it is not necessary to create a new resource; the resource can be shared between the copy and the original. Modifications must still create a copy, hence the technique: the copy operation is deferred until the first write. By sharing resources in this way, it is possible to significantly reduce the resource consumption of unmodified copies, while adding a small overhead to resource-modifying operations.

Translating this explanation to the examples given by the OP:

- `In[2]`: The statement `BB = AA` makes a shallow (lazy) copy of `AA` and "stores" it in `BB`. This is a very quick operation: the only thing to do is to write down that `BB` points to `AA`. `BB` is not an independent array; it depends on `AA`.
- `In[3]` and `In[4]`: The first statement (for $i=1$) sets `BB[[77]] = 1`, which triggers copy-on-write and prepares a deep (non-lazy) copy of `AA` in the space of `BB`, then modifies `BB[[77]]`. `BB` is now fully independent of `AA`. The subsequent 19999 assignments to elements of `BB` no not re-trigger copy-on-write because `BB` is not related to `AA` anymore.
- `In[5]`: In every loop iteration, the first statement `BB = AA` erases the old contents of `BB`, then establishes a fresh shallow (lazy) copy of `AA` just like in `In[2]`. The second statement in the loop then makes an assignment to `BB[[77]]`, which triggers copy-on-write, making `BB` a deep copy that can be modified independently of `AA`. It is this copy-on-write operation, which has to make a true copy of one million integer numbers (about 8 megabytes of data), that takes a significant amount of time.

A bit more profiling: a shallow copy seems to take about 190 nanoseconds (a good fraction of which may be the profiling overhead),

```
AA = RandomInteger[10, 1000000];
RepeatedTiming[BB = AA;] // First
(*    1.93599*10^-7    *)
```

whereas a deep copy of an array of $10^6$ integers takes about 340 microseconds,

```
RepeatedTiming[BB = AA; BB[[77]] = 5;] // First
(*    0.000340914    *)
```